# How can i implement auto slide on table pagination using Angular 6?

Tags: angular, carousel, angular-carousel

Is it possible to use Carousel and utilize my pagination on table or anything relate on auto scroll table page ?

I've tried implement carousel but it seems not work at all.

[image]

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="row" >
<div eds-tile class="xl-12" style="width: 700px">
    <eds-tile-title>User on Shift</eds-tile-title>
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="carousel">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">
       {{col.content}}
       </th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <div *ngIf='!tablePresetData' class="loading large"></div>
       <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 11, currentPage: p }; ">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
              <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>  
  </table>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

then, my dashboard.component.ts

```
constructor(private activityService: ActivityService, private router: Router) { }
public apiData;
public carousel;
public tables;

ngOnInit() {

this.carousel = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(()=> 'p:number = ${Math.random()}');

this.activityService.getAchievement().subscribe((res) =>  {
  this.apiData = res;

  var ids = [['Username', 1], ['Role', 2], ['today', 3], ['weekly', 4], ['monthly', 5], ['yearly', 6]],
  result = Object.keys(res).map(o => ids.map(([key, id]) => ({ id, content: res[o][key] })));
  this.tablePresetData = result;
})
```

There is bonus from me if anyone can help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngx-pagination to do your pagination is very simple to use.
install by : npm install ngx-pagination --save

example in the following link
[enter link description here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-pagination-implement-local-or-server-pagination-in-3-steps/)

regards.